# React app Using ARjs shwoing NFT marker Errors. How To Fix It?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, ar.js

I am developing an AR app using Reactjs and 'AR.js'.I created this react app using the 'create-react-app' npm package. And I am hosting it on firebase. But the problem is that when I try to run the app it is showing the following error.

```
> [error] Error loading KPM data: error reading data. [error] Error
> reading KPM data from /markerNFT_0.fset3 [error] ARToolKitJS(): Unable
> to set up NFT marker.
```

The camera loads but the marker show the following error on console. The NFT markers are fine I check with another app it worked fine.

[image]

**Below Is My Source Code**

**NB:-** Both the marker and the GLTF file actually getting downloaded. I checked it with the chrome dev tools network tab. They are fine. This to Script on index.html is for the Home.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
```

[DOWNLOAD GLTF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e8xX2MwRtVt6brHOSYRKezqKwqR_kMfI/view?usp=sharing)

[DOWNLOAD NFT MARKER](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZaMYtYq7XJTPrYSgVJ5_VelYzTGRf6F8?usp=sharing)

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from "./config/fire";
class Home extends Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state={
            
        }
    }
    logout(){
        fire.auth().signOut();
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <div class="arjs-loader">
                <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
            </div>
          <a-scene
            vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
            renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
            embedded
            arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
          >
            
            <a-nft
              type="nft"
              url="https://reactlogin3.web.app/trex"
              smooth="true"
              smoothCount="10"
              smoothTolerance=".01"
              smoothThreshold="5"
            >
              <a-entity
                gltf-model="https://reactlogin3.web.app/scene.gltf"
                scale="5 5 5"
                position="0 0 0"
              >
              </a-entity>
            </a-nft>
            <a-entity camera></a-entity>
          </a-scene>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like the NFT files are unreachable by the app. Make sure to give proper access permissions to your files.

Comment: @bpedazur I already checked it. And there is no problem with it. It's actually getting downloaded. I checked it with chrome dev tools network tab

Comment: any update on this?